# Unable to alter column data type in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, sqldatatypes

We imported database into BigQuery but a lot of columns are not in correct data types, many of them are stored as STRING. I want to fix them by change the data type in BigQuery

```
ALTER TABLE my.data_set.my_table ALTER COLUMN create_date SET DATA TYPE DATE;
```

But I got

```
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN SET DATA TYPE requires that the existing column type (STRING) is assignable to the new type (DATE)
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, as far as I know there is no way to convert data type from `STRING` to `DATE` using `ALTER TABLE` but to create it again with the schema you want.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE testset.tbl AS 
SELECT 'a' AS col1, '2022-05-16' AS create_date
 UNION ALL
SELECT 'a' AS col1, '2022-05-14' AS create_date
;

-- ALTER TABLE testset.tbl ALTER COLUMN create_date SET DATA TYPE DATE;

-- Query error: ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN SET DATA TYPE requires that
-- the existing column type (STRING) is assignable to the new type (DATE) at [7:25]


-- Create it again. 
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE testset.tbl AS
SELECT * REPLACE(SAFE_CAST(create_date AS DATE) AS create_date) 
  FROM testset.tbl;
```

Comment: You might want to use CAST to check things.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#safe_casting

Comment: As you already know, `CAST` will fail if the column has invalid format or empty string. If its' guaranteed that all the string in previous table has valid date format, `CAST` will be preferred to use.  Thanks for comment.

Comment: My thought is I want to use CAST to let BQ check if there are anything incompatible. SAFE_CAST will mute the error if there are any impaired or invalid data silently set to NULL.

Comment: I agree with your opinion.  What I was trying to say is that sometimes silently ignoring noise in the data would be better than nothing.  Depending on the situation, there will be someone who don't want their whole data pipelines be stopped because of small noise in data.

Answer (score 8):

Follow the steps below:

1. Rename the existing column

> ```
> ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable
> RENAME COLUMN create_date TO create_date_to_drop;
> ```

2. Add the column with the required data type.

> ```
> ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable
> ADD COLUMN create_date DATE;
> ```

3. Drop the renamed column.

> ```
> ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable
> DROP COLUMN create_date_to_drop;
> ```
>
> Note: As of now, DROP COLUMN won't work on the tables protected by customer-managed encryption keys.

Alternatively, you can drop the existing column in the beta version and add it with the new data type, but you need to wait until the [time travel](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/time-travel) window (7 days by default) to get over for adding the column with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

The proposed solution from @Jose is correct, but in case you do not want to lose your current data, you need to add one extra UPDATE step between steps 2 and 3.

1. Rename the original column with the wrong data type:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable
RENAME COLUMN create_date TO create_date_to_drop
;
```

2. Add a new column with the original name and the required data type:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable
ADD COLUMN create_date DATE
;
```

3. **Update a new column with original data, converted into desired data type:**

```sql
UPDATE my.data_set.my_table
   SET create_date = PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', create_date_to_drop)
 WHERE create_date_to_drop IS NOT NULL
;
```

4. Drop original (renamed) column:

```sql
ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable
DROP COLUMN create_date_to_drop;
```

This approach ensures you don't lose any data during the conversion process. It first renames the original column, then adds a new column with the correct data type, updates the new column with the converted data, and finally drops the original column.

Please note that the PARSE_DATE function converts the string data into a date format. The format string '%Y%m%d' is used as an example, and you should replace it with the actual format of your date strings.